# Auto-update Posts without refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, twitter, youtube, comments

I'm currently only using PHP to take user submissions, put them in a database, and echo them out on a page using SQL to select from a table, such as comments. I need a system that will automatically update comments without refreshing the page like on YouTube. The less the user has to manually update, the better.
I want it to work pretty much exactly how YouTube and Twitter function, where it'll say "x NEW COMMENT(s)" and clicking that updates everything.
My teacher recommended a JQuery function, but I don't have any background in that language so I don't know where to begin looking.

I'm at a complete impasse. I will update this if you guys need additional information to aid in my search.

Comment: Start at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, also jQuery isn't a language, it's a javascript library.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

You will need a HTML page with jQuery/AJAX that calls another PHP page. In that PHP page you do the DB request and then ideally return the data as JSON so that your frontend part can display it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

As every one says, AJAX is the way. You can find a simple blog I did on it [here](http://gavinsimpson.co.za/wp/2013/03/php-javascript-mysql-and-ajax/).